# Issue with hdbscan (ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, hdbscan

I know a number of people have posted about this before but I still can't resolve my error. I'm trying to import hdbscan but it keeps returning the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bf3184c2d1a0> in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 from pyproj import Transformer
----> 4 import hdbscan
      5 from scipy.spatial.qhull import ConvexHull
      6 from shapely.geometry import Point

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/hdbscan/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .hdbscan_ import HDBSCAN, hdbscan
      2 from .robust_single_linkage_ import RobustSingleLinkage, robust_single_linkage
      3 from .validity import validity_index
      4 from .prediction import (approximate_predict,
      5                          membership_vector,

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py in <module>
     19 from scipy.sparse import csgraph
     20 
---> 21 from ._hdbscan_linkage import (single_linkage,
     22                                mst_linkage_core,
     23                                mst_linkage_core_vector,

hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx in init hdbscan._hdbscan_linkage()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject
```

I have tried uninstalling numpy 1.19.5 and installing numpy 1.20 but it hasn't worked for me. I have installed the package hdbscan 0.8.27, I'm using Python 3.7.2 and I do not have admin rights to my MacBook. Appreciate any help!!

Comment: Changing `hdbscan` or `numpy` versions didn't work for me too. [This issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/457#issuecomment-773671043) might help, since you can't change the python version. Let me know if it does!

Comment: In my last resort attempt, I tried uninstalling numpy 1.19.5 and installing numpy 1.20.0, and somehow it worked this time. I was working on a Jupyter notebook and had kept it on in my earlier attempts, but this time, I just restarted Jupyter notebook after installing NumPy 1.20.0 and it worked... no idea how that happened though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I installed the hdbscan using the below method:

```
!pip install hdbscan --no-build-isolation --no-binary :all:
```

also installed the `numpy 1.9.2`

It works for me.